# cloud foundry app push fails due to disk limit

Tags: linux

Command:

```
cf push cf-mongo-client --docker-image mongoclient/mongoclient
```

Error:

```
ll_id"=>"2470c00a-181c-4965-bb2d-0ba3ad5c34aa", "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"failed to create container: running image plugin create: pulling the image: streaming blob `sha256:02200c4c842ea1c4b5c37a93b99ef2aff243d4ae116863aa562b4999f22df299`: writing blob to tempfile: uncompressed layer size exceeds quota\n: exit status 1", "crash_count"=>2, "crash_timestamp"=>1588547728558173147, "version"=>"55e0c7df-114d-4f4f-8252-d3c251c8f262"}
2020-05-04T00:15:28.60+0100 [CELL/0] OUT Cell 2470c00a-181c-4965-bb2d-0ba3ad5c34aa creating container for instance 37fbf199-092f-4a22-6b6f-5a0d
2020-05-04T00:15:50.29+0100 [CELL/0] ERR Cell 2470c00a-181c-4965-bb2d-0ba3ad5c34aa failed to create container for instance 37fbf199-092f-4a22-6b6f-5a0d: running image plugin create: making image: creating image: applying disk limits: disk limit is smaller than volume size
2020-05-04T00:15:50.29+0100 [CELL/0] ERR : exit status 1
```

Comment: 'uncompressed layer size exceeds quota' seems a good hint (?!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice Hint, Thanks gilles.

Reason:
Cloud foundry limits the container disk size to 1Gb by default. Its can be increased with the below command.

```
cf push cf-mongo-client --docker-image mongoclient/mongoclient -k 2G
```

Refer : http://cli.cloudfoundry.org/en-US/cf/push.html